# Create and Add TextView Progmmatically in android

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to add `TextView` progmmatically into may `RelativeLayout`.  it does not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

        tv.setText("Hello World");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rl.addView(tv);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Comment: Is `activity_main` an `id` given to your `RelativeLayout` in `activity_main.xml`? Is it crashing or just not showing up? Creating `View`s in xml is much easier unless there is a particular reason you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: @LASIAF post your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @codeMagic  its working. Thanx both of you for diverting my attention to id of layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` right after `super.onCreate`.

I've did this:

1. I went to main_activity.xml and added an attribute `android:id="@+id/activity_main"` to RelativeLayout.
2. Edited code:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
       RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
       TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

       tv.setText("Hello World");
       tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
       tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       rl.addView(tv);     

   }
   ```

   But still, the textView will overlap other generated items on RelativeView. Maybe you should consider using LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead.

Comment: If you were interested in the linearlayout code just comment again.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` will reinflate your layout, overriding the addition you made before it. Move it up, so it's the first thing after the `super` call. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

    tv.setText("Hello World");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rl.addView(tv);     
}
```

Comment: Still not Working. @MH.